# calculate time passed from a start date to a finish date

Tags: java, date

I would implement a method that receives in input two object date and calculate the time passed between these two. How can I implement something like that? Some idea?

Comment: Try [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what units do you expect the answer? Here's one possibility:

```
public static String timeBetween(Date start, Date end) {
    long timeDiff = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
    String diff = String.format("in days: %d | in hours: %d | in minutes: %d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff));
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: be careful with the absolute. you maybe in trouble for that!

Answer (score 1):

```
public long getDifference(Date strt, Date end){
    long s = strt.getTime();
    long e = end.getTime();
    return e-s;

}
```

Returns the number of milliseconds between the them

Answer (score 1):

A very crude method would be to take the time of each date object in milliseconds and subtract them to compute a duration.  With that duration, you can compute the number of seconds, minutes, days, etc in the duration.

This is a crude method because it might not be 100% accurate in all situations.  For instance,  daylight savings, leap years and, leap seconds all complicate this computation.

If you can accept these inaccuracies, the crude method is probably sufficient.  If you need better accuracy, using a third party library is advised.  [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) provides the concept of a [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) which is capable of computing the number of seconds, minutes, days, etc between two date instance.